# RIP Gary Kurtz, producer of Star Wars

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

*Star Wars* Producer [Gary Kurtz](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0476030/) has died at the age of 78. In addition to helping to convince the studio to fund *Star Wars* in the first place, he was also producer and second-unit director for *Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back* and is generally credited with encouraging Lucas to create a universal religion — The Force — for the movie series.

[image: On set for *Empire*]

After a much-publicised spat with Lucas over the direction the films were taking, he passed on producing what would become *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* as he felt it too similar to the previous films. He went on to produce *The Dark Crystal*, *Return to Oz* and *Slipstream*.

George Lucas has issued a statement via LucasFilm

> *Gary’s passing will be felt throughout the* Star Wars *family. Through
>   what were sometimes challenging shooting difficulties and conditions,
>   his contributions as a producer helped bring the stories to life
>   onscreen. My heart goes out to his family.*

Comment: Is he the one on the left or the right in that photo?

Comment: The one on the left is James Earl Jones so it has to be the other one.

Comment: @Matt - James Earl Jones' voice has quite the stage presence if you can see it in a photo.